# Going from directed to undirected graph with edge attribute retention

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to go from a directed network graph with edge attributes to an undirected graph and retain the edge attributes by adding them together. The following steps are to reproduce the problem

```py
import networkx as nx
g = nx.MultiDiGraph()

g.add_edge(1, 2, weight= 3)
g.add_edge(1, 2, weight= 4)
g.add_edge(2, 1, weight= 5)
g.add_edge(1, 3, weight= 2)
g.add_edge(2, 3, weight= 1)

# Add node properties
g.nodes[1]["property"] = "A"
g.nodes[2]["property"] = "B"
g.nodes[3]["property"] = "C"

print(g.edges(data=True))
print(g.nodes(data=True))
print("_____________________________________________"*2)

h = g.copy().to_undirected(reciprocal=False)
print(h.edges(data=True))
print(h.nodes(data=True))
```

in the output we notice that we lose the edge with weight 3

```
[(1, 2, {'weight': 3}), (1, 2, {'weight': 4}), (1, 3, {'weight': 2}), (2, 1, {'weight': 5}), (2, 3, {'weight': 1})]
[(1, {'property': 'A'}), (2, {'property': 'B'}), (3, {'property': 'C'})]
__________________________________________________________________________________________
[(1, 2, {'weight': 9}), (1, 3, {'weight': 2}), (2, 3, {'weight': 1})]
[(1, {'property': 'A'}), (2, {'property': 'B'}), (3, {'property': 'C'})]
__________________________________________________________________________________________
[(1, 2, {'weight': 5}), (1, 2, {'weight': 4}), (1, 3, {'weight': 2}), (2, 3, {'weight': 1})]
[(1, {'property': 'A'}), (2, {'property': 'B'}), (3, {'property': 'C'})]
```

Is this a bug in networkx? How can we retain all three edges so I can have

```
[(1, 2, {'weight': 3}), (1, 2, {'weight': 4}), (1, 2, {'weight': 5}), (1, 3, {'weight': 2}), (2, 3, {'weight': 1})]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NetworkX DiGraph() to Graph() with edge weights not summed, how to sum weights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778137/networkx-digraph-to-graph-with-edge-weights-not-summed-how-to-sum-weights)

Comment: @betaigeuze It doesnt exactly and doesnt seem like its scalable anyway